# Implement many similar (sub)classes in a maintenance-friendly way

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

This might well be something trivial, but I don't seem to be able to find an elegant way to implement something like this.

Consider the following sample code:

```
class Fruit {
    int m_weight;
    int m_color;
    int m_price;
  public:
    Fruit(int weight, int color, int price)
      : m_weight(weight)
      , m_color(color)
      , m_price(price)
    {}
}

class Apple : Fruit {
    int m_apple_specific;
  public:
    Apple(int weight, int color, int price, int apple_specific)
      : Fruit(weight, color, price)
      , m_apple_specific(apple_specific)
    {}
}

class Pear : Fruit {
    int m_pear_specific;
  public:
    Apple(int weight, int color, int price, int pear_specific)
      : Fruit(weight, color, price)
      , m_pear_specific(pear_specific)
    {}
}

[...]

static Fruit parseFruit(InputData input) {
  Fruit parsed_fruit;
  if (input.name == 'apple')
    parsed_fruit = Apple(input.weight, input.color, input.price, input.apple_specific);
  else if (input.name == 'pear')
    parsed_fruit = Pear(input.weight, input.color, input.price, input.pear_specific);
  return parsed_fruit
}
```

In my example I have a base class that combines common attributes and many sub-classes that are a bit more specialized. Now I have two concerns with this code:

- What I already dislike is that I have to duplicate the base class constructor for each and every of the child classes (in my real code they're obviously a bit more complex). Is there an easier way for this?
- What really makes me crave for a more elegant solution: Consider I now want to add a member `m_origin` to `Fruit`... As a consequence I have to adjust all subclasses!

Is this really just the way it's meant to be, or am I taking a completely wrong approach?

P.S. Don't assume the input data always being in a convenient "InputData" object (then I could probably just redesign my `Fruit` constructor), but sometimes one might want to use an `Apple()` or `Pear()` constructor directly.

Comment: Your `parseFruit` function doesn't work. You cannot pass polymorphic hierarchies by value.

Comment: `parseFruit` slices your poor fruits.

Comment: @aschepler: Sliced apples are actually really nice. They taste very fruity.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: Thanks, forgot something... Now edited.

Comment: @EduardBraun: I'm not entirely sure that works. You should most definitely consider writing unit tests and doing some test-driven development.

Answer (score 2):

A general guideline, which also helps your case, is that whenever a constructor is getting too many parameters, you probably want a separate "options" class:

```
struct FruitParams {
  int weight;
  int colour;
  int price;
};

class Fruit {
  public:
    explicit Fruit(FruitParams params)
        : weight_(params.weight)
        , colour_(params.colour)
        , price_(params.price) {}

    // ...
};
```

You can also make the options class a member type (`Fruit::Params`).

Then all your derived constructors take the following, simple form:

```
class Apple : public Fruit {
  int apple_specific_;

public:
  Apple(FruitParams params, int a) : Fruit(params), apple_specific_(a) {}
};
```

Changes to the base class can now all be done in one place, namely the base class constructor and its options class, without needing to touch all derived classes.